# Is there a way to destructure a struct partially?

Tags: rust, destructuring

I have a struct:

```
struct ThreeDPoint {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    z: f32
}
```

and I want to **extract two** of the three properties after instantiating it:

```
let point: ThreeDPoint = ThreeDPoint { x: 0.3, y: 0.4, z: 0.5 };
let ThreeDPoint { x: my_x, y: my_y } = point;
```

The compiler throws the following error:

```
error[E0027]: pattern does not mention field `z`
  --> src/structures.rs:44:9
   |
44 |     let ThreeDPoint { x: my_x, y: my_y } = point;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing field `z`
```

In JavaScript (ES6), the equivalent destructuring would look like this:

```
let { x: my_x, y: my_y } = point;
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`..` as a field in a `struct` or tuple pattern means "and the rest":

```
let ThreeDPoint { x: my_x, y: my_y, .. } = point;
```

There's more about this in [the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#ignoring-remaining-parts-of-a-value-with-).

Answer (score 10):

You can partially destructure a struct like this:

```rust
let point = ThreeDPoint { x: 0.3, y: 0.4, z: 0.5 };
let ThreeDPoint { x: my_x, y: my_y, .. } = point;
```